# Make list of unique names from the list of repetitive names

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Sheet 1, we register names of people who use our services. So a person can reappear in more rows of the same column. It looks like this

```
Name and family name
--------------------
John Doe
Peter M
Johnny F
John Doe
Michael L
Johnny F
...
```

Now, in the Sheet 2, I want to make a list of users so I have to extract unique values from the whole column.

For example, in the Sheet 2, I would have:

```
Name and family name
--------------------
John Doe
Peter M
Johnny F
Michael L
...
```

What is the formula for this?

Comment: there is no formula for that. You can either use a pivot table, or copy the list and data tab - remove duplicates.

Comment: I'd dump that out to CSV, run a bunch of things like sort and uniq on linux or some port of those tools, then import it back. But I'm odd.

Comment: Copy the column of Names to Sheet 2 and select it all use `Remove Duplicates` under `Data Tab`, `Data Tools` Group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the names in column **B**.  In **A1** enter **1** and in **A2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,B2)=0,1+MAX($A$1:A1),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Column **A** marks the unique names.

Then in *Sheet2* cell **A1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(ROW(),Sheet1!A:A,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: Can you help me? If I add top row as a title in the Sheet 2, then I will lose the first data. Try it, just add title to A1.

Comment: Got it. So simple, if you want to add title to Sheet 2, just decrement row() method: `=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(ROW()-1,Sheet1!A:A,0)),"")
`

Comment: @JoeM  Good Job!